# Java code for displaying loop

Tags: java

I've been making this little program that records the units manufactured, this is how it works

the user inputs the value of the units manufactured of each department

```
Dept 1: 1
Dept 2: 5
Dept 3: 2
Dept 4: 3
```

The results should be like this:

```
Dept 1: *
Dept 2: *****
Dept 3: **
Dept 4: ***
```

However when I try this code that I did it gives me a `null` value instead:

```
else if(e.getSource()==btnView){
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept1.getText());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept2.getText());
    int num3 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept3.getText());
    int num4 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept4.getText());

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; ++i) {
        str += "*";
        txtdept1record.setText(str);
    }
```

The result would go like this:

```
Dept 1: null*
```

This for loop above is only for the dept1.

Comment: You're concatenating `str` with `"*"`, and you're getting `null*`. What do you deduce about the value of `str`? What should it be instead to get `*`

Comment: it should have asterisk as the result depending on the number entered by the user.

Comment: That's what you expect it to have coming out of the loop. What is its value coming _into_ the loop?

Comment: That I understand. I'm trying to give you a hint. Try to reason. You're getting `null*` when concatenating `str` and `*`. So what is the value of `str`? What should it be instead to get the expected output: `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimize your loop as :

```
for (int i = 0; i < num1; ++i) {
    if( i == 0 ) //i.e. first time
        str = "";            
    str += "*";
}
txtdept1record.setText(str); //outside :-)
```

But this is not recommended, so use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < num1; ++i) {
    sb.append("*");
}
txtdept1record.setText(str); //outside :-)
```

---

Your (foolproof) code:

```
...
else if(e.getSource()==btnView){
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept1.getText());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept2.getText());
    int num3 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept3.getText());
    int num4 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept4.getText());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; ++i) {
        sb.append("*");
    }
    txtdept1record.setText(sb.toString());

    sb = new StringBuilder(); //empty it.

    //Same thing (i'll show once)

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; ++i) {
        sb.append("*");
    }
    txtdept2record.setText(sb.toString());
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it was the only thing missing, however, instead of having the same amount of asterisk as of the number entered it somewhat doubles or adds one asterisk to it.

Comment: @AdamJohnTan Yes, as for that... use `txtdept1record.setText(sb.toString());` at last: outside the loop.

Comment: what does the sb suggest? when I try to compile it, it gives me an error saying cannot find symbol.

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` did u write this line?

Comment: aw, sorry if I'm still new to this, I wrote the code, then it successfully run, however when I try to view, it doesn't have any asterisk in it anymore.it displays nothing.

Comment: @AdamJohnTan Take a look now... (remeember to empty or clear `sb` every time).

Answer (score 0):

Start with `String str = "";`

I think you have defined like this `String str;`

Comment: Thanks for that, it was the only thing missing, however, instead of having the same amount of asterisk as of the number entered it somewhat doubles or adds one asterisk to it.